# C2100 illegal indirection on auto&&

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, telegram

I'm trying to build Telegram Desktop on Windows 10 x64 with Visual Studio Community 2017, but it fails on `peer_list_box.h` multiple times, e. g. here:

```
int peerListPartitionRows(
        base::lambda<bool(const PeerListRow &a)> border) override {
    auto result = 0;
    _content->reorderRows([border = std::move(border), &result](
            auto &&begin,
            auto &&end) {
        auto edge = std::stable_partition(begin, end, [&border](
                auto &&current) {
            return border(*current); // fails here
        });
        result = (edge - begin);
    });
    return result;
}
```

The error looks like "C2100: illegal indirection" on each dereferencing of auto&&. I suppose the code is valid because it's Telegram Desktop from official repo.

Building with `/std:c++17`.

**UPD:** Determined type of `current` is `const PeerListRow &`.

Comment: What's the deduced type of `current`?

Comment: How to check it? Can't find it in VS.

Comment: Should be part of the error. If it's not, you can use [this trick](https://ideone.com/HW2u2K) to produce an error where it is a part of it.

Comment: "One True Brace" formatting really doesn't mix well with splitting the line

Comment: @StoryTeller, type is `const PeerListRow &`